# Strange text in matplotlib window under Docker

Tags: docker, matplotlib, conda

I'm running `matplotlib` in a Docker container on my MacBook. When I use `plt.show()`, it pops open the window on my screen and the figure I've created is just fine, but the text at the lower-left is gibberish (see example, below). How can I get it to show the usual x,y position of the cursor?

[image: Example]

Some additional details:

- It's a Centos 7 base docker image with our code layered on top. To keep the size down, we don't install the kitchen sink. Perhaps a package or two is missing?
- The effect is observed no matter what I plot.
- This is using matplotlib 2.0.2 installed via Conda.
- The default backend (according to `matplotlib.get_backend()`) is apparently `Qt5Agg`.
- I get a reasonable result if I use the `TkAgg` backend.
- Qt5 is coming from Conda.

Comment: This would require a bit of debugging from your side. First, check the backend, and if possible try a different one. (Qt5Agg, TkAgg, Macos?). The format is specified via [`ax.format_coord`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.format_coord.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.format_coord); check if it outputs the same gibberish into the console when `print`ing something.

Comment: Obligatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/833/

Comment: Aha! I get something reasonable if I use the `TkAgg` backend! Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest ! Extending the question with new information...

Comment: So maybe your docker image has an incomplete version of Qt5 included?

Comment: I've got a fine workaround (put `backend : TkAgg` into `~/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc`) so I'm not inclined to go and debug the Conda install. Thanks, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest! If you write an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Since I am at loss about the cause of this, it's probably not "the" answer. So if you feel like it, you may of course answer this yourself.

Comment: What docker image are you using to generate your container. I also would like to be able to `.show()` images like this on my windows machine...

Comment: I'm not the person to ask about display issues with Windows.